Parabolic maximum principle on the whole space
I am aware of the following maximum principle for the heat equation: Let $T \in (0, \infty]$ and $u$ satisfying
\begin{align}
\partial_t u - \Delta u = 0 &\quad  \text{on }\mathbb R^n \times (0, T] \\\\
u(\cdot, 0) = g &\quad  \text{on }\mathbb R^n 
\end{align}
for some function $g$. Moreover, if
$$|u(x, t)| \le Ce^{a |x|^2}$$
for every $(x, t) \in \mathbb R^n \times (0, T]$, then
$$\sup_{\mathbb R^n \times (0, T]} |u(x, t)| = \sup_{\mathbb R^n} |g(x)|.$$
This is for the heat equation though, do we have the same type of result for more general Parabolic types of operators ? More precisely: for $u$ satisfying
\begin{align}
L(u) = 0 &\quad  \text{on }\mathbb R^n \times (0, T] \\\\
u(\cdot, 0) = g &\quad  \text{on }\mathbb R^n 
\end{align}
with
$$L = \sum_{i, j} a_{ij}(x) \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i\partial x_j} + \sum_{i} b_i(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} + c(x),$$
the matrix $(a_{ij})$ satistying the ellipticity condition and $c(x) < 0$. If $u$ additionally satisfies some growth condition, do we alswo have
$$\sup_{\mathbb R^n \times (0, T]} |u(x, t)| = \sup_{\mathbb R^n} |g(x)| ? $$
The proof I know for the heat equation case strongly rely on the face that we are dealing with the heat equation, so I am not quite sure if I can generalise it to more general operators. Any help is welcome.
